# Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When Im trying to deploy functions to firebase I get this error: "Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined". This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "buildForDeploy": "npm run lint && tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.22.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My index.ts file:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";

initializeApp();
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;

/*Functions..........*/
```

It feels that I need to update something maybe? If I delete package-lock.json everything works perfectly but as soon as I rum npm install and get a new package-lock.json its the same issue again. I also tried to delete both nome_modules and package-lock.json but didnt work.

Comment: It seems that I solved it, in case someone else have the same issue: I uninstalled then reinstalled all firebase dependencies and changed 14 to 16 in node engines in package.json. Would be interesting if someone could explained what the real problem was and why it happened.